# rotate 3d object at specific point with photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, animation

Hello I want to create some simple assets for my iOS game but I'm very new in creating graphics. What I want to create is a moving punching ball.

I created a 3d model for that but was not able to rotate the 3d model so it looks like it is hanged up somewhere. It is always rotating to the center point of the model.

It looks like this:

[image]

So how can I rotate this object to the point on top of the object so it looks like a hanging punching ball getting punched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the anchor point in Photoshop. You can rotate based on the center of the bounding box of the object and reposition it to get the desired effect. Or you can create an object with a dummy point or something invisible on the opposite end of your object, so the center of the object will be the top of the visible punching ball.